# Is it possible to write a bootable operating system to a disk on a public library computer?

Tags: boot, usb, operating-systems

I would like to create a bootable USB drive or SD card on a public library computer (which will be inserted into a Raspberry Pi).

I assume the library computer would certainly allow me to download an operating system image, for example Ubuntu 21.04, and to copy that file to an insertable USB drive. However, I do not think I could reformat that drive as a bootable disk, because I would need an application to do so, and the public library computer would not permit me to install new software.

Is there any way around this? Is there some way I can download a bootable operating system and just copy it to the USB drive, so that I can do the rest of anything that needs to be done from my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: What is the OS on the library computer?

Comment: Raw disk access (needed to accomplish this) requires admin rights. You won't have them. Even if some image writer tool were present, you couldn't use it.

Comment: `Raw disk access (needed to accomplish this) requires admin rights` - not necessarily true, at least on Linux removable storage is typically owned by `plugdev` group and users belong to this group by default

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski Windows, presumably the latest version.

Comment: You might approach a librarian, or library technical staff, and explain the issue. My experience is that most library personnel are quite helpful, and someone might create Raspbian media for you. This is a known, safe, procedure.

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you.

Comment: My bet would be have a friend with a real computer help you.  You are very unlikely going to get the library staff to help you get pass admin reqs (nor is it what the library computers are for). For less than ten dollars, you can get an sd card preloaded with noobs which will allow you to do this install directly on your raspi but again.. *someone* you know has a computer and should be able to help you image a fresh disk.